# Proper Structuring for HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been reading around about best practices when doing developing a website. But I am still curious because the answers are found are mostly various, depend on a project's scope and many other considerations.

But just to cut it short, basically I wanted to ask about a proper formatting for 3 main elements in a website.

1. Header
2. Main/Body
3. Footer

How is the structure should be build? Are those three should be wrapped in a container like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And how is the styling should be done? I saw some people advised to use position:absolute for the CSS, while some others use relative instead. Sorry for the very basic question, but I am really confused about this at this current point of my learning.

Comment: Whatever works for you is fine (as long as it's valid HTML).

Comment: Try to visualize it as a document/ page of a book, maybe it could help. Everybody is doing it his own way, the most important is to keep it valid.

Comment: You can always check against [w3validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure your html is valid

Comment: As @mingos said, everything depends, whatever works for you as long it is valid HTML, here is the link to HTML validation of your projects: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: This is a far too broad and vague question for constructive answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML 5 example. Now a days best Layout width is 960. `.content{ width:960px }`

```
<!-- Outer Div -->
<div id="content">
    <!-- Inner Content -->
    <div id="content-inner">

        <!-- header -->
        <header>
          <div class="header">
            <div id="header_wrapper"></div>
          </div>
         </header>

         <!-- body -->
         <div id="content-body">
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <footer>
         <div class="footer">
            <div id="footer_wrapper"></div>
          </div>
    </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Yup I saw this yesterday during my reading and tried it out. Seems like will try to adapt this basic structure for my upcoming projects!

Answer (score 4):

The only reason a pseudo-standard like having a lot of wrappers exist is because it has proven useful when creating layouts. Basically it's all there for a reason. If you can design the page you want without having a `<div id="mainwrapper">` around it - then you don't need a main wrapper like that. :)

My tip would be to simply start creating a site and try to get it to look like you want using simple elements and CSS styling. If you can't make it work - for example you don't understand how to create a flowing column layout - then just search the web for something like "HTML flow column layout" and go from there.

**Edit:** "*Making it work*" usually means not having to result to using tables, a lot of magic numbers and loads of elements to create something simple.

A rule of thumb: *Don't cut and paste code/solutions if you don't understand **1)** what they do **2)** why you need them.* It's better to try building it yourself and then, as you work with it, realise why some patterns (clearfix, avoiding tables, floating layouts and so on) are so common. It might not save you time right now, but it definitely will make you a better developer in the long run.

Comment: Oh and another thing, wouldn't it be resource-hungry if there too many <div> used in a single HTML file? Is there anything like how many <div> you can use for one file?

Comment: In general, don't worry about element count. Modern browsers can handle A LOT. When people make games in HTML/JavaScript, they can use hundreds, if not thousands, of elements. If you need a div for some structuring reason - add a div!

Comment: Thank you thank you really much! This is a really good community indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

HTML layouts are very subjective and it depends on your requirements / preference as a developer.  The two main layouts are **static** (using absolute positioning etc) and **floating** (using floated divs for a liquid layout).

[This is a good article that covers these principles in more depth](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/)

Basically, you should be using block level elements i.e. **div** tags to structure your page.  In cases where you have tabular data **tables** are perfectly fine, but don't use them for your layout as they're slow to render and can make things difficult when you need full control on your page layout.

Best practice for styling suggests that you use CSS to position and style your elements via class attributes and not inline.  This will then allow you to minify your CSS scripts and reduce the overhead of your page.  CSS has evolved very well, and there are a lot of selectors available to you to reduce the number of classes in your markup.  See [CSS selectors at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for more information on them.

Answer (score 1):

When writing HMTL you need to bear in mind readabillity of the markup and the ease with which it can be altered in the future.

Try and bear in mind **seperation of concerns**. Which parts of your site are related to others in a structural sense and which are not reliant on others. Try and group the reliant elements together (using div's etc.) and keep the unrelated ones apart.

Try and structure your CSS in a similar way, if 2 elements position is reliant on the other, but the other isn't, group the related elements under a single class and then use inheritance to structure the differences. where as the unrelated one should probably be in a separate css class altogether.

Also try and structure your CSS so it can be re-used.

Bit general those points but hopefully it'll help?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of sites which offer various SEO friendly layouts and they all provide the css

http://www.searchenginefriendlylayouts.com/

http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2011/02/seo-friendly-two-column-layout/

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm